# Java ^ regex does not match new line in string

Tags: java, regex, newline, match

this is my String

```
REGISTER sip:192.168.178.1 SIP/2.0
Call-ID: bla@192.168.178.60
CSeq: 1441 REGISTER
From: "620" <sip:620@192.168.178.20>;tag=bla
To: "620" <sip:620@192.168.178.20>
Via: SIP/2.0UDP 192.168.178.60:59488;branch=bla;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
User-Agent: bla
Contact: *
Expires: 0
Content-Length: 0
```

So this string has several newlines.
My Regex is in this form:

```
sipRequest = sipRequest.replaceFirst("(From: \")(.*)(\" <sip:)(.*)@(.*)>", "$1$2$3$4@" + sipServer + ">");
```

This Regex matches, but not the following one:

```
sipRequest = sipRequest.replaceFirst("(^From: \")(.*)(\" <sip:)(.*)@(.*)>", "$1$2$3$4@" + sipServer + ">");
```

Note: Only difference is the "^" sign before "From".
So why does this expression not match? It starts at a new line, so it should match.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting the JavaDoc of `Pattern`:

> By default, the regular expressions ^ and $ ignore line terminators and only match at the beginning and the end, respectively, of the entire input sequence. If MULTILINE mode is activated then ^ matches at the beginning of input and after any line terminator except at the end of input. When in MULTILINE mode $ matches just before a line terminator or the end of the input sequence.

So you need to set the multiline flag, because the default meaning of `^` is **beginning of string**, not beginning of line.

Answer (score 3):

The operation `^` works only if you are using `Pattern.MULTILINE`. Since `string.replaceAll()` creates patterns without options you have to create pattern yourself, than create matcher and use replacing facilities of matcher.

Comment: Thanks very much for fast answering.
I've read http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html and there was it written with new line. 

What is faster, leave as it is or activate multiline?

If my RegEx can be expressed more simple, please tell.